# h2 disconnect and connect

Tags: connect, h2, ormlite, disconnect

i got a problem when i'm closing an h2 connection(release database) and try to connect to another h2 database(debug database).

Snipplet to connect:

```
this.connection = new JdbcConnectionSource(connectionString);
```

Snipplet to disconnect:

```
this.connection.close();
```

ConnectionString:

```
jdbc:h2:file:/data/data/my.app/databases/myapp
jdbc:h2:file:/data/data/my.app/testdatabases/myapp
```

Then instead of using the "new" connection the old one is used.
I'm using different directories for the databases. In both cases when i try to toggle between database1 and database2 the .lock and .trace files are not deleted in their directories.

I want exclude implmentation failures on my side.
I'm using h2(current version) with ormlite on android 4.2.2.

Comment: So if you are creating a new ConnectionSource you need to create new DAO classes, right?

Comment: Right after the reconnect i need to call DaoManager.createDao(connection, class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then instead of using the "new" connection the old one is used.

If you are creating a new `ConnectionSource` then you will need to re-create all of your DAO classes and clear the DAO cache from within the `DaoManager`.  Each of the DAO classes has a copy of the old connection source that it uses.

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(connectionString);
DaoManager.clearCache();
Dao<Foo,Integer> fooDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Foo.class);
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps but now after reconnectin a SQLException is thrown: "Session closed". It happens when i query first the "new connection". But the database and tables are created successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: Hrm.  I just added the following test and it seems to work fine @user2379652.  https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/DoubleDbOpenTest.java

Comment: Thx I also tested this with a smaller database. There it also works. But i think 18 Tables shouldnt be a problem. A crazy thing that the exception stil is thrown but it works. I could read and save data from the database.

Comment: Could it be that you are dealing with a existing foreign collection _after_ the database is switched?  Foreign collections have a cached DAO that might try to access the closed session @user2379652.

Comment: Well I wrote ORMLite so I better know the limitations.  :-)  You should refresh any objects with foreign collections with the new DAO to remake the foreign collections.  Best of luck @user2379652.

Comment: Sorry still not working, but I'll try it tomorrow again. Maybe its a mistake on my side.